# Fortran dim(x,y), to what end?

Tags: history, fortran

In Fortran dim(x,y) returns the difference x-y if the result is positive; otherwise returns zero. What was it intended to be used for? What is the meaning behind the name dim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably it comes from dimension, i.e., the length, width, height of something.  Since none of these values can be negative it's calculated as the positive difference.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is (in some older literature on Fortran) defined as DIM(A,B):=A-MIN(A,B), I'd say that the name is just an abbreviation for "difference from minimum".